# Smoke effects to Unity or Unreal

Tags: smoke-simulation, unity, unreal-engine

Blender smoke effect to Unity or Unreal

I’ve seen a few demos where people create some great smoke simulation in Houdini and then are able to bring this exact sim into a game engine.  I’ve also seen pipelines where they use Houdini for all their game effects.

I created a smoke effect I like in Blender.
Would anyone have any direction or helpful links that demo how to export this to a flip book or maybe a point cache or something that’s useable in a game engine?  Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export VDB files from Blender to a game engine that supports VDBs, it's actually quite simple.

Assuming you have a working smoke simulation, all you have to do is bake it into OpenVDB format, which happens to be the default format to begin with:

[image: export VDB]

You will find your VDB sequence files in the baking folder, data subfolder. You can import them as sequence in your preferred game engine.

If you want to export a flip book, the manual way is essentially to just render images of your smoke simulation with either alpha, or as a black and white, and assemble them into a sprite sheet.

There are some addons to automate parts of this process, one of which is explained on this very website here:

[fluid simulation - Rendering smoke to texture sheet - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192541/rendering-smoke-to-texture-sheet)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  Just so I can understand better, if I have an animated smoke trail that I export as a vdb, and the engine supports it, does that just open up as an animated smoke trail?  Or is there more set up that needs to be done once in engine?

Comment: That depends on the game engine and isn't in the scope of this website.

Comment: You are right.  Thank you for your previous response.  That gets me going in the right direction!